# Resetting SP password using jumper P20 doesn't work on Sun Fire x4600 M2

Tags: sun, password-reset, lom

The [Sun Fire X4600 M2 Servers Service Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19121-01/sf.x4600/819-4342-18/html/z40007e91027886.html#z40007e91027414) says installing a shorting jumper across the P20 header pins will reset the SP password and clear the BIOS password. I installed the jumper then powered up the SP and the system fully as this note suggests:

> You must allow the entire server, not just the SP, to reboot to main
>   power mode to complete the password reset. This is because the state
>   of the P20 jumper cannot be determined without the host CPU running.
>   Wait until the end of POST, when you see the **CMOS password cleared by
>   jumper** message, after which both the BIOS and SP passwords are reset.

I attached a monitor to the system and saw it saw **CMOS password cleared by jumper**, however I still cannot log into the SP / ILOM with what should now be reset to the default:

```
username: root
password: changeme
```

I tried logging in on the serial console, then via ssh as root and finally via the https method, but in all instances the `changeme` password did not work.

So far I have not tried re-installing or upgrading the firmware, but I'd rather avoid that unless I have to go that route.

Also, there is no password on the BIOS so I am able to get into that with no problems.

[image]

Comment: +1 for literal screenshot.

Comment: @WesleyDavid I figured a photo of the screen would help head off people asking questions about whether I had installed the jumper properly or not.

Comment: Sun box, Dell Screen, Labelled Toshiba. Confusing much? ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Surely it could be worse... `s/Sun/Oracle/g`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have no extra insight on the reason why the jumper wouldn't work, but you can reset the password using ipmitool, with the commands:

```
ipmitool user list 1

<Find the appropriate user id in the returned list>

ipmitool user set password <userid> <newpassword>
```

Adapted from [How to reset iLOM root password on Sun/Oracle X server](http://www.akamit.com/blog/2011/11/how-to-reset-ilom-root-password-on-sunoracle-x-server/).